# Is it possible to get mouse input on tkinter window screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a personal project in which I open an image(gif) in a Toplevel() window in tkinter. Using nested loops I open multiple images like this:

```
for img in range(10):       *#####EX: 10 gif files*
    imgfile = "path %i.gif" %img *## Each file is named in series e:g 0, 1, 2,...,9*
    for i in range(30):     *#####considering each gif has 30 frames/slides*
        gif = PhotoImage(file=imgfile, format="gif -index %d" %i)
        canvas.create_image(o,o, image=gif, anchor=NW)
        canvas.update()
>>>
```

After canvas.update(), I would like to wait for the user to click on the tkinter window screen anywhere before next iteration of the outer loop starts.
What command do I have to use next to '>>>' in ln 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

i = 0
main = Tk()
flag = IntVar(value=1)

def click():
    flag.set(1)

bt = Button(main, command=click, text='continue')
bt.grid()

print('looping')
while i < 50 and flag.get():
    i += 1
    flag.set(0)
    print(i)
    bt.wait_variable(flag)

main.mainloop()
```

I think this little demo code can help you to solve the problem.
Every time you click the button, increased i would be printed on screen, just like your one-more picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the mouse click event to the window and update the image in the mouse click event handler.  Below is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

file_idx = 0
image_idx = 0

def update_image():
    global file_idx, image_idx
    imgfile = 'path %i.gif' % file_idx
    canvas.gif = tk.PhotoImage(file=imgfile, format='gif -index %d'%image_idx)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.gif, anchor='nw')
    image_idx = (image_idx + 1) % 30
    if image_idx == 0: file_idx = (file_idx + 1) % 10

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: update_image())
root.mainloop()
```